# What Hz should I put for my microphone and my speakers

Tags: microphone, speakers

I wanna ask you about how much Hz should I put on my microphone (44100Hz CD quality 16 bit or 48000Hz DVD quality 16 bit?

And, how much Hz to put on my Headphone speakers (44100Kz 16 bit Cd quality  OR 48000Hz 16 bit DVD quality?

Answer (score 1):

Both options (41.1kHz, 48kHz) have advantages and disadvantages, so what is best is up to you or depends on other needs. The golden rule: the higher the sample-frequency is, the better is the sound-quality (although I think only a trained ear may able to resolve the difference). On the other side, a higher sample-frequency will lead to bigger audio-files in the case you perform records. This is a relevant point regarding your input-device (microphone). But you may need the signal from the microphone as input for an application and the signal should match the requirements of the application.

If we use the same sample-frequency for the input- and output-device, we avoid conversion from 41.1kHz to 48 kHz or back. This will use less resources. If the settings are different, it will work though, but use a bit more resources.